# How to fix: pods "" is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot watch resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run my spark over k8, I have set up my RBAC using the below commands:

`kubectl create serviceaccount spark`

`kubectl create clusterrolebinding spark-role --clusterrole=edit --serviceaccount=default:spark --namespace=default`

Spark command from outside of k8 cluster:

```
bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://<master_ip>:6443  --deploy-mode cluster  --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.caCertFile=/usr/local/spark/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/ca.crt --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark   --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=bitnami/spark:latest test.py
```

error:

```
   Exception in thread "main" io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: pods "test-py-1590306482639-driver" is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot watch resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatchConnectionManager$1.onFailure(WatchConnectionManager.java:206)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.failWebSocket(RealWebSocket.java:571)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$2.onResponse(RealWebSocket.java:198)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Throwable: waiting here
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.Utils.waitUntilReady(Utils.java:134)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatchConnectionManager.waitUntilReady(WatchConnectionManager.java:350)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.watch(BaseOperation.java:759)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.watch(BaseOperation.java:738)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.watch(BaseOperation.java:69)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.Client$$anonfun$run$1.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.Client$$anonfun$run$1.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2542)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.Client.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication$$anonfun$run$5.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:250)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication$$anonfun$run$5.apply(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:241)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithResource(Utils.scala:2543)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.run(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:241)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.k8s.submit.KubernetesClientApplication.start(KubernetesClientApplication.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:845)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
20/05/24 07:48:04 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/05/24 07:48:04 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-f0eeb957-a02e-458f-8778-21fb2307cf42
```

**Spark Docker images source**  --> docker pull bitnami/spark

I am also giving my **crt** file here present on the master of k8 cluster. I am trying to run `spark-submit` command from another GCP instance.

### Edit

I have created another clusterrole with cluster-admin permission but still it is not working.

Comment: ca.crt exists in directory etc/kubernetes/pki/ on the system where you run the command?

Comment: it is present on the k8 master server not on the client node from where I am hitting it @ArghyaSadhu

Comment: But the spark application will run on worker nodes not on master node.So it will not have access to it

Comment: so do I need to make it available on the client from where I am running it? @ArghyaSadhu

Answer (score -1):

spark.kubernetes.authenticate applies only to deploy-mode client, and you run with deploy-mode cluster

Depending on how you authenticate to the kubernetes cluster, you might need to provide different config parameters starting with spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission (these config parameters apply when running with deploy-mode cluster). Look for ~/.kube/config file and search for the user. For example, if the user section specifies

access-token: XXXX

then pass spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthToken